# View page from ProjectReference not reflected without restarting main project asp.net MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, runtime-compilation

I am building a shared UI - razor page in a Lib project (Visual Studio), the purpose is to add the Lib project as ProjectReference to multiple places. I am stuck at finding a way to reflect the .cshtml changes immediately to the browser without restart the main project, which waits me a lot of time.

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

Setup line above works when I coded UI in main project, but Lib project doesn't.

More information: .Net5.0, Asp.net MVC, Razor page.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options =>
{
    var libraryPath = Path.GetFullPath(
        Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "..", "NameOfRazorClassLibrary"));

    options.FileProviders.Add(new PhysicalFileProvider(libraryPath));
});
```

Related to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio):